# Recover Windows after removing drive with 100mb system partition

Tags: windows-7, partitioning

I have a two hard-drive setup, let's say X and Y, X older than the other. My Windows installation was on X. After noticing the X hard drive started failing I decided to backup everything on Y and reinstall the system on it.

After backing everything up I deleted the system partitions on drive X, leaving around 64 gigs of unallocated space and installed Windows on drive Y.

Upon removing the failing hard drive from the system, Windows refused to boot. Upon further inspection I realized that Windows installed itself on drive Y, but it also made the 100MB partition the old, failing drive.

How can I get a working system with everything on drive Y after removing drive X without reinstalling Windows?

Comment: Physically remove the failing drive **before** reinstalling?

Comment: The idea is I don't want to reinstall. Missed that in the question. Edited.

Comment: What was in the partition on drive X? Was it the system reserved partition? That is 100MB on Windows 7. If so see [What is the System Reserved Partition and Can You Delete It?](http://www.howtogeek.com/192772/what-is-the-system-reserved-partition-and-can-you-delete-it/)

Comment: "To delete the System Reserved partition, you’d first have to move the boot files from the System Reserved partition onto the main Windows system drive.

This is harder than it sounds. It will involve messing with the registry, copying various files between drives, updating the BCD store, and making the main system drive the active partition. "

Comment: "This may be possible, and you’ll find some guides walking you through the process on the web. However, it’s not officially supported by Microsoft and we don’t recommend it. "

Comment: It might be easier to reinstall ...

Comment: It is indeed the System Reserved Partition. I was away from a Win computer and didn't remember or search its name.

I really don't like the fact that Windows does this and offers no way to recover from it... Reinstalling is going to be a pain...

Comment: Then read the link above carefully ;)